# c# authenticate and open network

Tags: c#, networking, authentication, shortcut

i need a simple way to put a shortcut on a desktop that when clicked opens windows explorer to a network (\mynetwork) and authenticates.  it sounds like it would be easy - a c# console app - but I am not sure where to start with this.

Comment: So a server, then: is it running in a domain?

Comment: yes, it will be something like \\194.xxx.xxxx, username, password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the login info to the cred manager using this:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSRunProcessAsUser-e4b10d6f/sourcecode?fileId=23561&pathId=1786330904

and running explorer.exe using process.start and supplying the \networkaddress
as args to the processinfo for process.start